# Recording and playback midi sequence using AudioKit

Tags: swift, midi, audiokit

I faced the same issue as in the following question:
[Recording midi with Audiokit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815702/recording-midi-with-audiokit/55695498#55695498)

The problem is pauses in record differs the real pauses.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in source code of the linked question:

```
track.add(noteNumber: b, velocity: c, position: startPosition, duration: currentPosition - startPosition, channel: 0)
```

It has been passed currentPosition, not startPosition.